# MSM content update not working with OSGI nodes

Tags: osgi, aem

I want to prevent few properties from replicating in LiveCopy. I have followed the below documentation  [http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html#Excluding Properties and Node Types From Synchronization](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html#Excluding%20Properties%20and%20Node%20Types%20From%20Synchronization) .

But since I need to create a OSGI node in my project structure I followed the following link http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#OSGi Configuration in the Repository

Steps Followed

1. Created node with name
   com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.ContentUpdateActionFactory under
   config node in apps/myproject
2. Added the property cq.wcm.msm.action.excludedprops and value
   "propertyname" to be excluded

But the properties are not updating in system/console/configMgr. Still the property is getting copied on roll out

Any pointer on where I am making mistake

Thanks In advance

Veena

Answer (score 0):

OOTB there's already a sling:OsgiConfig node for ContentUpdateAction for the authoring environment at [0].
If you need a different config you should overlay the node in /apps and make the necessary changes that suit your project.

Alternatively you can change the node at [0] directly, however since it's under /libs this is not recommended.

[0] /libs/wcm/msm/config.author/com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.ContentUpdateActionFactory

Answer (score 0):

You can try using excludedprops with ContentCopyActionFactory instead of using ContentUpdateActionFactory